# Firebase fetching data from last post

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, key

Every time the user logs into the app `private var currentKey: String!` is `nil` so this gets called:

```
databaseRef.child("OMG_Pictures").queryOrdered(byChild: "timeStamp").queryLimited(toLast: 5)
```

and it always pulls the old posts. How can I save the current key so that the user doesn't always have to see the same posts every time, but instead they continue from where they left off and the database fetches new posts only? (similar to what the social media apps do)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking to paginate back, which requires that you (in this case) call `queryEnding(atValue: ...)`. By adding this to your query, you can make it "skip" the items you've already seen, essentially paging back through the results.

Say that your current query returns items with these timestamps:

```
 96
 97
 98
 99
100
```

To use `queryEnding(atValue: ...)` you will need to know the timestamp value of the oldest item you've already seen, in this case `96`. You pass that into the next query:

```
databaseRef
  .child("OMG_Pictures")
  .queryOrdered(byChild: "timeStamp")
  .queryEnding(atValue: 96)
  .queryLimited(toLast: 6)
```

And now you get:

```
 91
 92
 93
 94
 95
 96
```

You'll note that we're getting 6 items now. That's needed since the last item in this new query's result is one we've already gotten before. So we need to retrieve an extra item, and remove the overlapping item with client-side code.

Also note that it is possible that the same value for timestamp occurs multiple times in your messages. In that case you need both the value of timestamp *and* the key of the oldest item you've seen, and pass both into `queryEnding(atValue: ..., childKey: ... )`.

Comment: okay, but when I refresh (not re-running the sim) the app I start back at 100 - 96 instead of 96 or 91 onwards. Would you like me to update the question with the code that I did base off of your answer?

Comment: You'll need to persist the information upon a reload, so that you can rebuild the query. Doing that seems a separate problem, one that has little to nothing to do with Firebase. I'd recommend searching for how to persist information, as I'm quite sure you're not the first one trying to do so.